# WSGI import app from python package yields 500

Tags: apache2, mod-wsgi

I want to deploy my python app on apache so I made a hello world app (contained in one python file) and imported the app object from there and it worked. This was just to test out things.

Then I move my app file there and tried the same with it. I try to import the app object( now from a python package), nothing blows up, however when I visit the server I get a 500 error code. 
Note: the application works just fine if I run it with python. It is not broken.

File structure:

```
app.wsgi   main(this is the python package)  hello.py(this is the simple app)
```

In app.wsgi I have this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/var/www/html')
from hello import app as application
```

and that works, but when I change it to :

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/var/www/html')
from main import app as application
```

it gives me a 500.

Any ideas as to why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently I had to call run in my __init__.py file.

If anyone finds this helpful keep it otherwise take it out.